# UWP, MySQL, populated ListView, implement CRUD operations

Tags: c#, mysql, listview, win-universal-app, crud

I'm developing windows universal application, and already found some limitations in UWP. So now I'm using MySQL database.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=client_surname}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=client_name}"></TextBlock>
```

XAML (these TextBlocks are in ListView)

In Data.cs i got something like this:

```
        public class Tablename
    {
        private string _client_name;
        public string client_name
        {
            get { return _client_name; }
            set { _client_name = value; }
        }

        private string _client_surname;
        public string client_surname
        {
            get { return _client_surname; }
            set { _client_surname = value; }
        }
    }
```

And code is like this:

```
  using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("xxx"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand readCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM clients", connection);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    demodata.Add(new CloudTable { client_name = reader.GetString(1), client_surname = reader.GetString(2) });
                }
            }
        }
        listView1.DataContext = demodata;
    }
        public ObservableCollection<CloudTable> demodata = new ObservableCollection<CloudTable>();
```

So question, can I make button "EDIT" and by clicking it go to new blank page, with new TextBoxes, and fill them with selected listview item, So I can edit and update selected entity ?

Comment: I would be very grateful if someone would give an example or a solution that would suit for my project. *I plan to work with queries.

Answer (score 1):

Can you? Yes. But this isn't a tutorial website. What your looking for is a MVVM UWP application. By searching 'C# UWP crud' in Google I found this tutorial

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/

This will help you create what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Universal Platform comes prepared with sqlite you just need to configure your nuget packages and reference the right libraries.

Head on over to this page, it explains all you need to know to start using sqlite on your UWP apps.

> http://igrali.com/2015/05/01/using-sqlite-in-windows-10-universal-apps/

As for the edit button sure you can ;)
Just try something like this:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    MyObject obj = listview1.SelectedItem as MyObject;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourNewPage), obj);
}
```

And then on your new page you can receive your object like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    MyObject obj = e.Parameter as MyObject;

    textbox1.Text = obj.MyName;
    textbox2.Text = obj.MyOtherValue; 
    //etc etc etc
}
```